# How to properly model Product Compatibility Matrix in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

So, I have a problem that I am trying to solve. I have one database that contains products and another that contains a cross-reference between two products. I have been able to generate the following schema and SQL procedure to display info the way I want (see SQL fiddle):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fdc4/1

It essentially mimics an Excel sheet with column and row references, where the column can be a specific product compared to a slew of other products listed as row headers. The end goal is not only to display it, but if you are an admin user, update the compatibility status or add/update the notes field.

My problems:

1) I an unable to display the actual ProductCompatibility table ID in the table.
2) The Notes field as shown doesn't correlate to the selected products properly. The only data that seems to be displayed properly is the compatibity info columns.

I am building the web site using ExtJS, but it shouldn't matter really. I want to know how I can model the data and obtain the proper index, so I perform an update.

If I should model the database differently, or have a different SQL stored proc, then I am open to ideals on achieving my goal.

Answer (score 0):

To select, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(pr1.ProductName,'' '', pr1.ProductRelease) as Product1,
CONCAT(pr2.ProductName,'' '', pr2.ProductRelease) as Product2,
pc.`Record1`,
pc.`Record2`, 
pc.`IsCompatible` as IsCompatible
pc.`notes` as Notes 
FROM ProductCompatibility pc 
JOIN Products as pr1 on pr1.id = pc.Record1
JOIN Products as pr2 on pr2.id = pc.Record2
```

Comment: What does this do exactly? Does this replace a part of the SQLFiddle script? I doesn't replace entirely.

Comment: So, unfortunately, I do not know if this addresses what I am trying to do? I am trying to display the info as a Dynamic Pivot Table, but what you are showing is a static row view of the data which can be easily updated. 

My idea is to be able to capture updates within the Dynamic Pivot Table.

Comment: I'm just describing a typical data model for matrix scenarios. It's more usual to have it like this on the database side, and then pivot it in the UI code

Comment: That is pretty much how it is modelled in the database. However, the customer wants to have it displayed in the manner I described.